# How PHP parse object sdtClass

Tags: php, parsing, object, stdclass

When I run the SOAP client, I get the following response.

How can I parse this struct in php?  I wanna take only  `NUGGETNAME` value.

And how can take length of result count?

```
        object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
          ["GetHotelNuggetResult"]=>
          object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
            ["HotelNugget"]=>
            array(9) {
              [0]=>
              object(stdClass)#4 (7) {
                ["NUGGETNAME"]=>
                string(19) "Yaz Tatili Otelleri"
                ["NUGGETORDER"]=>
                string(2) "10"
                ["PARENTUNIQUECODE"]=>
                string(10) "AS_SOL_UST"
                ["REWRITENUGGETNAME"]=>
                string(19) "yaz-tatili-otelleri"
                ["TITLE"]=>
                string(19) "Yaz Tatili Otelleri"
                ["UNIQUECODE"]=>
                string(5) "YTOTL"
                ["WEBNUGGETID"]=>
                int(306)
              }
              .......//other results

              }
    }
```

Comment: Define parse? You have some nice objects so what do you want to do with it more?

Comment: i wanna print value of NUGGETNAME on the screen.

Comment: `$obj->PropertyName` this is the way you can access properties of your objects in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$O = response(....);
var_dump($O->GetHotelNuggetResult->HotelNugget[0]->NUGGETNAME);
```

Comment: it works but result is  string(19) "Yaz Tatili Otelleri" how can eliminate string(19) and " character

Comment: @enginar Get rid of var_dump() (i.e. replace with echo)

Comment: last one , how can learn of result count

Comment: "HotelNugget" seems as an Array, so you can do simply `count(...->HotelNugget)` or `$count = 0; if(!empty(...->HotelNugget)) $count = count(...->HotelNugget);`

Comment: I would give a more "generalistic" suggestion, learn PHP?